# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'...Need support

Tags: python

The code is

```
class Demo():
    count = 0
    def __init__(self,name, no):
        Demo.count = Demo.count + 1
        self.name = name
        self.no = no
    def display(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.no)
    def count(self):
        print(Demo.count)

D = Demo('Mohan',20)
D.display()
D.count()
```

When I run this code, I am getting the following error message.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'
>   Process finished with exit code 1

How to get rid of this error and make use of class variable?

Comment: You already have 2 `count`s: variable and method name, try to rename one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your variable (count) cannot have the same name as your method (count)

```
class Demo():
    number = 0
    def __init__(self,name, no):
        Demo.number = Demo.number + 1
        self.name = name
        self.no = no
    def display(self):
        print (self.name)
        print(self.no)
    def count(self):
        print(Demo.number)
D = Demo('Mohan',20)
D.display()
D.count()
```

Returns

```
Mohan
20
1
```

I just changed the variable name

Answer (score 0):

You can make this code working just by renaming this function:

```
def count(self):
      print(Demo.count)
```

or either this variable:

```
count = 0
```

You can use `_` (underscore) in your variable or function name to avoid collisions.

It's all about naming so when you try to add function + 1 Python interpreter raises error.